# How to set baseUri in itext 7 convertor property when we deploy the application as an war file

Tags: java, itext, pdfhtml

I am using itext7 pdfhtml to convert html file to a pdf. Now the problem i am facing is, i set the baseUri property of converterProperties to point to my file that resided in "src/main/resources" folder and everything worked fine using spring boot embedded container. But when i deployed the app as an war, file not found exception is being thrown. Please help me, i am stuck with this issue for quite sometime.

Answer (score -1):

Use classpath: relative url.  Not the hard coded full url path.

Comment: can you please give me an example, because in the html file there are references to images which will be referred based upon the URL set in this property.